# Libraries not found when running R script at boot

Tags: r, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, boot

I been with the following for a long time now, and can't seem to make it work.

What I am trying to do is to automatically shutdown an Ubuntu EC2 instance once an R script runs.

For that I am using `/etc/rc.local` where I have a line like the following

```
Rscript /home/ubuntu/shutDown.r > /home/down.log 2>&1
```

The script gets executed but the log shows

```
Error in library(DBI) : there is no package called 'DBI'
Execution halted
```

`DBI` is a library loaded by `shutDown.R` but I know the problem is not that there is no `DBI` package because when I run the script using the command line like

```
Rscript shutDown.r
```

everything works. Even when I run

```
sudo sh /etc/init.d/rc.local start
```

It works.

What can be preventing the script to load libraries during boot time? I tried deleting `DBI` and the error appear on the next library in line. So there is definitely something going on with the way that the script looks for libraries during boot. I don't know how to solve this so if anyone can provide any tip I will really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install your local R packages in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` --- which is the default location anyway --- and they will be found by default.  In the case of DBI you could also install `r-cran-dbi` which goes into the other default directory.

This has been the default in the Debian / Ubuntu package I look after for close to a decade. And it works.  Otherwise use explicit library location arguments to `library()`.

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me a ton of hours! I will ask earlier next time :)